# Embed widgets into QWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

Basically I want to create a window using `QtGui.QWindow()` instead of `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`.

I want to do this because I want to have access to `QWindow` functions such as:

- `startSystemMove()`
- `setTitle()`
- `setWindowStates()`
- `startSystemResize()`

At first I thought you make the window class inherit `QtGui.QWindow`, but if you do that, it just creates an empty window.

However, `QWindow` functions do work. So my guess is that I have to somehow input the `QMainWindow` (or the widgets inside it) into the `QWindow`, but I have no idea how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that there is an XY problem since the objective is to modify properties of the `QWindow` associated with the `QWidget` but instead it asks how to embed a `QWidget` into a `QWindow`.

`QWidget` creates a `QWindow` after using the `show()` method and it can be accessed using the `windowHandle()` method.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainwindow = QMainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()

    window = mainwindow.windowHandle()

    window.setTitle("Foo")

    def start_resize():
        window.startSystemResize(Qt.TopEdge)

    def start_move():
        window.startSystemMove()

    def maximized():
        window.setWindowStates(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, start_resize)
    QTimer.singleShot(10 * 1000, start_move)
    QTimer.singleShot(15 * 1000, maximized)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:** Some methods of the `QWidget` are a wrapper of the `QWindow` methods such as `setWindowTitle()` or `setWindowState()`.